# What is the logic behind { height: 100%; position: absolute; } getting browser height?

Tags: css

Okay, so there's three ways to get browser window height (NOT full web page height, that is the difference).

1. [Vertical height unit, explained wonderfully here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)
2. jQuery
3. [Using { height: 100%; position: absolute; } on an element. (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/u7fdyjv4/)

I do not understand the logic behind #3 on my list.

`height: 100%` and `absolute` positioning. `height: 100%` fills up the parent. Positioning `absolute` also is relative to the parent, so shouldn't it take the full height of the page. How does the viewport come into play?

I know that `fixed` is relative to the viewport, but I thought that was the difference from `absolute`. The `height: 100%` div does have a parent, its the `body`, it should be relative to that.

Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An absolutely positioned element is placed in relation to the first parent that is also positioned. The body element has no positioning applied to it in your example. Therefore, the div has no reference since absolutely positioned elements are taken out of the normal flow.

If you assign positioning to the body, typically  `position:relative;`, you will find what you are looking for.

[W3C CSS2.1 explanation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#comp-abspos)